# How to add facebook like button in Titan light box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, facebook

I'm loading some photo by Titan lightbox & I need to load facebook like botton in this lightbox. My website link http://www.historikindia.com/kashmir.html.

How can I add to load "Like Button" script in Titan lightbox?

looking something like this. 
www.jsfiddle.net/kmLWf

Comment: You might ask facebook developers for help in this thing. However I don't think that this code would stop working with any script language.

Comment: However, if you are seeking help to load the like button on some event. You might consider having a look at the developer documentations from the Titan Lightbox team.